# Speak.js not working

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I am trying to use Speak.js to let my webpage read strings, it doesnt seem to be working eventhough i am using the same codes in the tutorial. and there is no compiling errors, this is the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">    
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/speakGenerator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/speakClient.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Play() {
        speak("oooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    }
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<input type="button" value="play" onclick="Play()" />
</asp:Content>
```

this code in a html file works perfectly, but when i use it in asp.net as shown above, it doesnt work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery plugin for Text to Speech - demo</title>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="speakGenerator.js"></script>
<script src="speakClient.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">    
<button id="button" onclick="speak('I know I know I know')">Talk</button>
<div id="audio"></div>   
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the javascript console?

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: JavaScript does not "compile". Look at the errors on the clientside.

Comment: try firebug or the webdevelopment console of firefox and look which errors come up on clientside

Comment: there is no error, it compiles. Ok so more details: 'code'            <html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery plugin for Text to Speech </title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="speakGenerator.js"></script>
    <script src="speakClient.js"></script>
   
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"> 
    <button id="button" onclick="speak('I know  know')">Talk</button>
    <div id="audio"></div>   
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
 this code is working when i try it in a notepad, not in visual studio, but not when i use it in asp.net like the code shown

Comment: edit your question and paste this code there :)

Comment: sorry, still getting used to this

Comment: You are sure that the all scripts are loaded correctly right?

Comment: in your html code shown above, there is a <div id="audio"></div>, maybe this is missing in the asp page?

Comment: I added it , :s still the same problem

Comment: Well, still the problem? You tried to start it in Firefox? Because FF is at the moment the only browser who works with speak.js..

Comment: Yes, i'm trying it in firefox, is it possible that it doesnt work in asp.net and i'm just wasting my time?